# how to make a server side pagination with angularjs $resource ?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display a table with a large collection of elements. I want to paginate the table and load only the elements displayed on the current page. Now, the json is loaded with `$resource`.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180451/2112538) that it's a good idea to pass the pagination infos (currentPage, pagesCount and elementsCount) inside the json header.

**How can I access to those infos which are in the json header from angular?**

Here is the basic js structure:

```js
angular.module('App.services', ['ngResource']).
factory('List', function($resource){
    return $resource('url/of/json/:type/:id', {type:'@type', id:'@id'});
});


angular.module('App.controllers', []).
controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'List', function($scope, List) {
    var $scope.list= List.query({offset: 0, limit: 100, sortType: 'DESC' });
}]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle pagination and count with angularjs resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465768/how-to-handle-pagination-and-count-with-angularjs-resources)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the AngularJS $resource documentation, it should be possible to do this:

```
List.query({offset: 0, limit: 100, sortType: 'DESC' }, function(data, responseHeaders) {
  // you can access headers here
});
```

Comment: yes this is the way to display previous page and next page links, but what if i want to display direct links to each page ? i need the (currentPage, PagesCount) infos from the server. Or am i missing something ?

Comment: That can be calculated based on `limit` and `offset`. And you know those. Unless `I` am missing something :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. to calculate the pagination, you need the `limit` and `offset` and also the total number of elements (`elementCount`) which i would like to pass through the json header. what do you think ?

Comment: working ! i have to pass the parameter to `responseHeaders` like this : `responseHeaders("date")`