# AngujarJS server-side pagination grand total items using $resource

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-resource

I'm trying to implement server-side pagination on an AngujarJS app but haven't figured out how to get the grand total (not the per-request total) items in a given JSON response without having to do an additional request:

```
$scope.books = [];
$scope.limit = 3;
$scope.offset = 0;

$scope.search = function () {
    Books.query({ q: $scope.query, limit: $scope.limit, offset: $scope.offset },
        function (response) {
            $scope.books = response;
        }
    );
};

$scope.previous = function () {
    if ($scope.offset >= $scope.limit) {
        $scope.offset = $scope.offset - $scope.limit;
        $scope.search();
    }
}

$scope.next = function () {
    if ($scope.offset <= $scope.limit) {
        $scope.offset = $scope.offset + $scope.limit;
        $scope.search();
    }
}
```

I've been looking at great contributed directives such as `ng-table` and `ng-grid` which already implement this as well as other useful features but I just want to be able to implement this one functionality from scratch to really learn the basics.

Comment: Add the total number of items in the response returned for each request.

Comment: @ranru: Thanks but I believe there should be a better approach rather than modifying the object collection itself.

Comment: If the JSON response contains all the items then you should be able to get that from the length property. However, if each it only contains a subset of the result, I don't think there is any other way than getting the value from the server.

Comment: It's a subset -- that's the purpose of `$scope.limit`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make a server side pagination with angularjs $resource ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460003/how-to-make-a-server-side-pagination-with-angularjs-resource)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are struggling with your api more than angular.

See the answer below for suggestions for the api.

[What’s the best RESTful method to return total number of items in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715981/whats-the-best-restful-method-to-return-total-number-of-items-in-an-object)

Comment: Django Rest Framework offers a nice paginated result object that offers `total`, along with `next` and `previous` URLs in addition to the paginated result array for example.